# Unable to decrypt email address using openssl_decrypt & AES in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I'm trying to create an unsubscribe link for my email marketing system. In the email I created an unsubscribe button and after it's clicked I'm trying to pass the email address and table id via the URL, with encryption like below:

```
<?php 

$email_id = '123456';
$addto = 'test@gmail.com';

$email_id= openssl_encrypt($email_id, "AES-256-CBC", "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff");
$encto= openssl_encrypt("$addto", "AES-256-CBC", "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff");

 ?>
```

after click button url is like

```
https://sub.example.com/unsbscribe.php?id=bK2XGnJms0rzPuQOpvauGw==&eadd=WoN/K2t4xjKb057c++EIhg==
```

unsbscribe.php:

```
<?php

$eid    = $_GET['id'];
$eaddr  = $_GET['eadd'];

$eid    = openssl_decrypt($eid, "AES-256-CBC", "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff");
$eaddr  = openssl_decrypt($eaddr, "AES-256-CBC", "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff");

?>
<p>Your Email Address is <address><?php echo $eaddr; ?></address></p>
<p>Your Id is: <?php echo $eid; ?></p>
```

Please check this link of my real project which will output $_get Data and unencrypted data also
[https://ems.vozcodex.com/unsbscribe.php?id=bK2XGnJms0rzPuQOpvauGw==&eadd=WoN/K2t4xjKb057c++EIhg==](https://ems.vozcodex.com/unsbscribe.php?id=bK2XGnJms0rzPuQOpvauGw==&eadd=WoN/K2t4xjKb057c%20%20EIhg==)

Using

```
var_dump($_GET);
Result: array(2) { ["id"]=> string(24) "bK2XGnJms0rzPuQOpvauGw==" ["eadd"]=> string(24) "WoN/K2t4xjKb057c EIhg==" }
```

I'm only able to decrypt the table id - which is '123456', but not the email address. I tried various `openssl_decrypt` methods but am unable to decrypt the email address. email address always comes empty.

Can you please help to point out the issue. I am using PHP 7.4 (ea-php74).

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: So you're saying that `openssl_decrypt` returns `false` when you try to decrypt the email address, is that correct?

Comment: "after click button url is like" - what does that mean? How do you generate these links? Do the `$_GET` parameters **really** contain the encrypted strings, or something else? Maybe URL encoding screws this up?

Comment: On the face of it, this should work - demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/cbd02 . Of course that demo doesn't include the fact of it being placed into an email and then input again via the URL parameters, but that shouldn't make any difference unless something is somehow being truncated in the process, or encoding changed, or extra characters added somehow. What debugging have you done? Have you checked what exact values are received in $_GET, for example? Have you verified the email link contains exactly what's supposed to? Work backwards until you find a point of failure.

Comment: yes problem is email address always comes empty.

Comment: I recieved the $_GET variable properly.

Comment: Are you sure? Show us the output of `var_dump($_GET);` then, so we can see what you mean. If it's received properly, the decryption code should work.

Comment: Try to encode the ciphertexts URL safe, e.g. with Base64url instead of Base64 (or with Url encoding in addition to Base64).

Comment: The chrome error seems to be irrelevant, it's a client-side error, it looks like some extension trying to parse your URL somehow, from what I can tell. It won't interfere with what PHP is doing, and it's nothing to do with the more useful information I asked you to provide.

Comment: Dear i just add real project link where you may get some isea.

Comment: Please read [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) . And aside from those reasons, I'm not going to go and click on your random link anyway, just for basic security.

Comment: All I asked you to do is update your question with the output of `var_dump($_GET);`. It should not be difficult. If you want some help please respond to that request.

Comment: You put the ciphertexts in a URL without encoding them URL safe, so they will be extracted wrong with GET. Try a `urlencode(openssl_encrypt(...))`. The `urldecode()` will be executed automatically with GET.

Comment: Using

var_dump($_GET);
Result: array(2) { ["id"]=> string(24) "bK2XGnJms0rzPuQOpvauGw==" ["eadd"]=> string(24) "WoN/K2t4xjKb057c EIhg==" }

Comment: And these are the **exact** values generated by encrypting the values? For example, why are there two spaces in `$_GET['eadd']`? Should they appear where they do?

Comment: With those results we can now reproduce your issue - demo: https://onlinephp.io/c/6ea77 . It seems encoding of the `+` signs went wrong. Try url-encoding the encrypted values properly when generating the URL for the email, as suggested by Topaco. `+` (and several other characters) has a special meaning in URLs.

Comment: @Topaco & ADyson Thank you very much. now its working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems encoding of the `+` signs went wrong. Try url-encoding the encrypted values properly when generating the URL for the email, as suggested by Topaco in the comments. `+` (and several other characters) has a special meaning in URLs.

e.g. something like:

```
$email_id = openssl_encrypt($email_id, "AES-256-CBC", "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff");
$encto = openssl_encrypt($addto, "AES-256-CBC", "25c6c7ff35b9979b151f2136cd13b0ff");

$url = "https://sub.example.com/unsbscribe.php?id=".urlencode($email_id)."&eadd=".urlencode($encto);
```